# macOS SwiftUI Navigation for a Single View

Tags: macos, navigation, swiftui, macos-catalina, swiftui-navigationview

I'm attempting to create a settings view for my macOS SwiftUI status bar app. My implementation so far has been using a `NavigationView`, and `NavigationLink`, but this solution produces a half view as the settings view pushes the parent view to the side. Screenshot and code example below.

Navigation Sidebar

[image]

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            NavigationView{
            NavigationLink(destination: SecondView()){
                Text("Go to next view")
                }}
        }.frame(width: 800, height: 600, alignment: .center)}
}

struct SecondView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{

                Text("This is the second view")

        }.frame(width: 800, height: 600, alignment: .center)
    }
}
```

The little information I can find suggests that this is unavoidable using SwiftUI on macOS, because the 'full screen' `NavigationView` on iOS (`StackNavigationViewStyle`) is not available on macOS.

Is there a simple or even complex way of implementing a transition to a settings view that takes up the whole frame in SwiftUI for macOS? And if not, is it possible to use `AppKit` to call a View object written in SwiftUI?

Also a Swift newbie - please be gentle.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here is a simple demo of possible approach for custom navigation-like solution. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / macOS 10.15.4

[image: demo]

*Note: background colors are used for better visibility.*

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var show = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            if !show {
                RootView(show: $show)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .transition(AnyTransition.move(edge: .leading)).animation(.default)
            }
            if show {
                NextView(show: $show)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .background(Color.green)
                    .transition(AnyTransition.move(edge: .trailing)).animation(.default)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct RootView: View {
    @Binding var show: Bool
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Button("Next") { self.show = true }
            Text("This is the first view")
        }
    }
}

struct NextView: View {
    @Binding var show: Bool
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Button("Back") { self.show = false }
            Text("This is the second view")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a great solution. Any idea how to stop the `.animation()` modifier also applying to all subviews though?

Comment: is it possible to pass data List->Detail with this approach?

Answer (score 12):

I've expanded upon [Asperi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12299030/asperi)'s great suggestion and created a generic, reusable `StackNavigationView` for macOS (or even iOS, if you want). Some highlights:

- It supports any number of subviews (in any layout).
- It automatically adds a 'Back' button for each subview (just text for now, but you can swap in an icon if using macOS 11+).

[image: Example view on macOS]

**Swift v5.2:**

```
struct StackNavigationView<RootContent, SubviewContent>: View where RootContent: View, SubviewContent: View {
    
    @Binding var currentSubviewIndex: Int
    @Binding var showingSubview: Bool
    let subviewByIndex: (Int) -> SubviewContent
    let rootView: () -> RootContent
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack{
                if !showingSubview { // Root view
                    rootView()
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                        .transition(AnyTransition.move(edge: .leading)).animation(.default)
                }
                if showingSubview { // Correct subview for current index
                    StackNavigationSubview(isVisible: self.$showingSubview) {
                        self.subviewByIndex(self.currentSubviewIndex)
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .transition(AnyTransition.move(edge: .trailing)).animation(.default)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    init(currentSubviewIndex: Binding<Int>, showingSubview: Binding<Bool>, @ViewBuilder subviewByIndex: @escaping (Int) -> SubviewContent, @ViewBuilder rootView: @escaping () -> RootContent) {
        self._currentSubviewIndex = currentSubviewIndex
        self._showingSubview = showingSubview
        self.subviewByIndex = subviewByIndex
        self.rootView = rootView
    }
    
    private struct StackNavigationSubview<Content>: View where Content: View {
        
        @Binding var isVisible: Bool
        let contentView: () -> Content
        
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                HStack { // Back button
                    Button(action: {
                        self.isVisible = false
                    }) {
                        Text("< Back")
                    }.buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
                    Spacer()
                }
                .padding(.horizontal).padding(.vertical, 4)
                contentView() // Main view content
            }
        }
    }
}
```

More info on `@ViewBuilder` and generics used can be found [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/custom-containers).

Here's a basic example of it in use. The parent view tracks current selection and display status (using `@State`), allowing anything inside its subviews to trigger state changes.

```
struct ExampleView: View {
    
    @State private var currentSubviewIndex = 0
    @State private var showingSubview = false
    
    var body: some View {
        StackNavigationView(
            currentSubviewIndex: self.$currentSubviewIndex,
            showingSubview: self.$showingSubview,
            subviewByIndex: { index in
                self.subView(forIndex: index)
            }
        ) {
            VStack {
                Button(action: { self.showSubview(withIndex: 0) }) {
                    Text("Show View 1")
                }
                Button(action: { self.showSubview(withIndex: 1) }) {
                    Text("Show View 2")
                }
                Button(action: { self.showSubview(withIndex: 2) }) {
                    Text("Show View 3")
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(Color.blue)
        }
    }
    
    private func subView(forIndex index: Int) -> AnyView {
        switch index {
        case 0: return AnyView(Text("I'm View One").frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity).background(Color.green))
        case 1: return AnyView(Text("I'm View Two").frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity).background(Color.yellow))
        case 2: return AnyView(VStack {
            Text("And I'm...")
            Text("View Three")
        }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity).background(Color.orange))
        default: return AnyView(Text("Inavlid Selection").frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity).background(Color.red))
        }
    }
    
    private func showSubview(withIndex index: Int) {
        currentSubviewIndex = index
        showingSubview = true
    }
}
```

**Note:** Generics like this require all subviews to be of the same type. If that's not so, you can wrap them in `AnyView`, like I've done here. The `AnyView` wrapper isn't required if you're using a consistent type for all subviews (the root view’s type doesn’t need to match).

Comment: is it possible to pass data List->Detail with this approach?

Answer (score 0):

Heyo, so a problem I had is that I wanted to have multiple navigationView-layers, I'm not sure if that's also your attempt, but if it is: **MacOS DOES NOT inherit the NavigationView.**
Meaning, you need to provide your DetailView (or `SecondView` in your case) with it's own `NavigationView`. So, just embedding like `[...], destination: NavigationView { SecondView() }) [...]` should do the trick.

But, careful! Doing the same for iOS targets will result in unexpected behaviour. So, if you target both make sure you use `#if os(macOS)`!

However, when making a settings view, I'd recommend you also look into the [Settings Scene](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/settings) provided by Apple.

Answer (score 0):

Seems this didn't get fixed in Xcode 13.

Tested on Xcode 13 Big Sur, not on Monterrey though...[image]

Answer (score -8):

You can get full screen navigation with

```
 .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
```

Comment: Ahh if only it was that simple, I get a build error "StackNavigationViewStyle' is unavailable in macOS".

Comment: Just saw on the Apple Documentation it's only available with Apps created with Mac Catalyst

Comment: Would this also work to pass data LazyGrid() -> Detail for ex? I tried and wasn't able to make that work since you need to load both views at once

Comment: It's not supported in Xcode 13 beta 3 / macOS 12 SDK yet. Can't wait another year.

Comment: I found this very useful, was not aware of style