# Hide Navigation Bar SwiftUI for MacOS 11.1

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

Is there a way to completely hide the Navigation bar on the MacOS version of SwiftUI?  I know there's navigationBarHidden(true) but that only works on iOS from what I've seen.

So I'm trying to have something like a title screen when the app boots so the user has to press enter and it goes to different screen.

```
struct TitleScreen: View {
    var body: some View {

        ZStack {
            Color.customColor
                .ignoresSafeArea(.all)

            NavigationView {
                 NavigationLink(destination: MainMenu()) {
                     /*nothing*/
                }.keyboardShortcut(KeyEquivalent.return, modifiers: .init())
            }

            VStack {
                Text("Press Enter!")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MainMenu: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Main Menu")

        Image("placeholder")
    }
}
```

I'm trying to have the Navigation bar that appears due to NavigationView not be there.

Also it would be nice if the original View in TitleScreen went away in some way but I can worry about that later.

Comment: Do you mean the menu bar?

Comment: Whatever the big grey bar is that pops up when I use ```NavigationView{NavigationLink()}```

Comment: @CaptainLupa can you add a screenshot? I think you're talking about the toolbar but I'm not sure

Comment: <https://imgur.com/a/qxjexEQ> The "Text()" won't be there ideally and I can just hit enter to change views.

Comment: @koen I think I added enough to explain, although I'm not sure how even word the question to be honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so it turns out that wasn't even my problem, and this is really a duplicate question of this: [macOS SwiftUI Navigation for a Single View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61424225/macos-swiftui-navigation-for-a-single-view).